how to building model when using optaplanenr or timefold
I have a school scheduing problem.
Problem description:
schedule each course into a timeslot. (ps: not need into a room).
Hard constraint:

same course in a class need consecutive. the length consecutive of course is 2. for example,  Math course in class A, may need one that consecutive length is 1 and other one that consecutive length is 2. so there are two math course in class A, that total count timeslot of math needing is 3.

same course in different class that has same teacher need to be taken together. for example , music course in class A and class B, amd the teacher of music course is same one teacher Ann. when timeslot of music course in class A is slotA, the timeslot of music course in class B must be slotA.


my solution is building one model using build-in hard constraint to handle the hard constraints.
Are there any other effective ways to solve this problem?

School timetabling can contain many constraints. The Timefold Quickstarts repository already has a few pre-implemented so I would suggest having a look at those for further inspiration.
As per your questions:

"same course in a class need consecutive": You could take the studentGroupSubjectVariety constraint in the file I liked above and invert it (because now it does the opposite of what you want) + change it to a hard constraint. You could also just leave it as a soft constraint and have a look at the results.

"same course in different class that has same teacher need to be taken together.": This is a trickier request since on a larger dataset and you should think about additional questions:

How many students can 1 teacher handle? (If there is also a Class C, D and E and all of them have music teacher Ann... are they all at the same time?). This introduces a form of "capacity", which could be a constraint by itself.
While rooms are not a concern for you, still something you should think about when building your constraints.



When trying to model that 2nd part, you run into the issue that you introduced a Many-to-Many relationship between a Lesson/Timeslot and StudentGroups/Class. Looking at the modeling guidelines, this is not a good strategy. I do not have a clear answer for that one yet, but I'll see what I can come up with.

Thanks, I looked at the example code, and it has given me a lot of inspiration. I have other a question about using "Joiners.equal()" . The official documentation of Timefold  often directly compares the field of two objects, like Joiners.equal(lesson -> lesson.getCourse()). When it comes to comparing the field of the field  within an object, will indexes be used? like Joiners.equal(lesson -> lesson.getCourse().getType() ) ,   will indexes be used ?

Yes, they will. The only time they won't is if you use Joiners.filtering(...).
